# Do I need to validate the Request in Controller after?

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I have this **StoreMessageRequest**

```
public function rules(): array {
        return [
            'message' => [
                'required',
                'string',
                'max:60',
            ],
        ];
    }
```

which leads to MessageController

```
public function store(StoreMessageRequest $request, Message $message) {
     ......
}
```

I can then run query of

```
$message = new Message([
        'user_id' => auth()->id(),
        'message' => $request->message
    ]);

    $message->save($message);
```

is this safe or should I use `$request->safe()->message` ~ `$validated = $request->safe()->all();`
or `$validated = $request->validated();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `store()` method will only be called if validation passes.

`$request->safe()->message` would almost be the same as `$request->message` the difference being when using `safe()` you get a `ValidatedInput` instance with the validated data

`$request->validated()` and `$request->safe()->all()` is the exact same thing. But every time you call the `safe()` method you are creating a new `ValidatedInput` instance

`$request->safe()` is the same as `new ValidatedInput($request->validated())`

`$request->all()` includes non valid data